# Removing duplicates from a list but returning the same list

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I need to remove the duplicates from a list but return the same list.
So options like:

```
return list(set(list))
```

will not work for me, as it creates a new list instead.

```
def remove_extras(lst):
  for i in lst:
    if lst.count(i)>1:
        lst.remove(i)
  return lst
```

Here is my code, it works for some cases, but I dont get why it does not work for remove_extras([1,1,1,1]), as it returns [1,1] when the count for 1 should be >1.

Comment: First of all, you should never (until absolutely necessary) modify the object that you are iterating over in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use slice assignment to replace the contents of the list after you have created a new list. In case order of the result doesn't matter you can use `set`:

```
def remove_duplicates(l):
    l[:] = set(l)

l = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]
remove_duplicates(l)
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Ah, beat me to it. FYI, the `list` wrapping isn't needed: `l[:] = set(l)` will work just fine (internally, I believe it listifies, but it's cheaper than explicit conversion).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for the comment, updated the answer. I thought slice assignment requires a list but any iterable seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `OrderedDict` which removes the duplicates while maintaining order of the list.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> itemList = [1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2]
>>> itemList[:]=OrderedDict.fromkeys(itemList)
>>> itemList
[1, 2, 0, 3]
```

This has a Runtime : **O(N)**

Comment: Without slice assigning back to `itemList`, this doesn't actually answer the question. You want `itemList[:] = OrderedDict.fromkeys(itemList)`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, ofcourse. I just showed how it works. Assigning it back is the easy part after all.

Comment: It was the only actual question the OP had; it's fine to demonstrate a better way to uniquify, but you do need to answer the question to (how to dedup in place so the original `list` is deduped).

Comment: I get your point @ShadowRanger. Have updated the answer. My usual ideology is to guide others, and point them in the right direction. That according to me should be enough and helps the most :D